# Buying an online Seminar that is recorded by a Jew on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

There is an online seminar that is being given on Shabbos by a Jew. The recording is being made available for those that can't make it on Shabbos. What do the sources have to say about a Jew buying the recording of the seminar (after shabbos)?

(In case more detail helps, the jew is giving the seminar over zoom and making a recording of it himself. I would also be curious if the answer differs if non-jews were making the recording.)

Comment: This exact question is discussed here. https://halacha2go.com/?number=826

Comment: @Chatzkel I think it's a little different. The issue with a "one-time event" is that it's outside the Jew's control and couldn't be put off to after shabbos. In this case, the Jew is giving the seminar and could theoretically record a presentation any time, so the concept of *bich’dei sheya’asu* may be more applicable.

Comment: If the recording is made specifically for people who can't make it on Shabbos then you can't buy it. If the recording is being made anyway, and it happens to be convenient for you because you can't make it on Shabbos, then you can.

Comment: @shmosel kdai sheyaaseh is only if a non-Jew does it, no? Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Shalom The linked article says, "for benefitting from the work of a *mechalel Shabbos*, many poskim state that we must wait *bich’dei sheya’asu*."

Comment: @shmosel thanks. Classically in halacha it was just for an aino-yehudi. They weren't going to make a takana for the weird notion of a yehudi occasionally mechalel shabbos. Sounds like the poskim cited feel that a regular *mechalel shabbos* should be included in that takkana, or something to that effect. It makes sense from a certain perspective ... but we should also cry about it.